# What is a tail sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, terminology

The question is self-explanatory.

What is a tail sequence or a tail of convergent sequence?

Thanks

Comment: A tail of a sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ is $a_n,a_{n+1},\dots$ for any $n$.

Comment: The tail of a sequence or series is the end-behavior of the sequence after perhaps finitely many have been excluded. Usually I refer to it when saying that the tail of a series is where the divergence occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_1, \; a_2, \; a_3, \; \dots$ be a sequence, which I'll call $S.$ Then a *tail of* $S$ is any sequence of the form $a_n, \; a_{n+1}, \; a_{n+2}, \; \dots$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Thus, a tail of a $S$ is simply all the terms of the $S$, in the same order, except that at most finitely many initial terms of $S$ are omitted. Note that one of the tails of $S$ is $S$ itself, and every tail of $S$ is a subsequence (of a certain special type) of $S$.

Comment: One of the tails of **S** is **S** itself when n=1. Is that right?

Comment: And what is the use for creating such a definition?

Comment: Yes, choosing $n=1$ in the formulation I gave says that $S$ is a tail of $S.$ (This property, that $S$ is a tail of $S,$ is just a useful convention.) The main reason for having this notion is what Clayton said in a comment to your question, namely that a sequence converges if and only if at least one of its tails converges. The idea is that for convergence and divergence issues, you don't have to worry about the first few terms -- what matters is how the terms behave from some point (possibly distant from the beginning of the sequence) onward.

Comment: The idea of a tail of a sequence is analogous to how, when considering the limit of a function at a point, you only have to consider the values of the function in some (deleted) neighborhood (perhaps very small) of the point. A good illustration of this idea is how one can show that [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function) is continuous at the irrationals and discontinuous at the rationals, although this particular example might be too advanced for you at this time.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.